# how to access child components of the panel? unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Im getting this Error in this statement Im trying to get image object in Dropzone area all scripts are attached to the editor. I already checked them .I couldnt find problem please help.
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6e7G.png)

```
     public void CardDetect()
    {
        D = new DropZone();


        List<Image> listofcard = new List<Image>();

for (int i = 0; i<D.transform.childCount - 1; i++)
        {
            if (listofcard != null)
            {
                listofcard.Add(D.transform.GetChild(i).transform.GetComponents<Image>()[i]);

            }

        }

        for(int i = D.transform.childCount - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            // this.PlaceholderParent.transform.Find("Pane").GetComponent<Image>().tag = "ileri"
            if (D.transform.GetChild(i).transform.name == "ileriprefab1")
            {
                ileri = true;
            }


            if (D.transform.GetChild(i).transform.name == "sağprefab")
            {

                sağ = true;

            }
            if (D.transform.GetChild(i).transform.name == "solprefab")
            {
                sol = true;
            }

            if (D.transform.GetChild(i).transform.name == "fprefab")
            {

                f = true;
            }




        }
```

> Blockquote
>   [Dropzone Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3Cx0.png)

Comment: im getting error in that statement----->for (int i = 0; i<D.transform.childCount - 1; i++)

Comment: `DropZone` seems to inherit from `MonoBehaviour`. If that's the case then you shouldn't be using the `new` keyword to create instance of it. I also see the warning from Unity from your screenshot. See the duplicate for what to do.

Comment: I try your way bu my Dropzone script also have interface =  MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler. but its not work :/ here is what i change ---->
    {
        D = GameObject.Find("carddroparea").GetComponent<DropZone>();

Comment: You need to ad "Edit"" to the question and post the class. Also post what you've one after reading the duplicate and explain your new issue

Comment: its not work same error again ---->D = GameObject.Find("carddroparea").GetComponent<DropZone>();

Comment: 1.Edit your question and post the DropZone script.

Comment: Stack gave the error "too much code" i shared Dropzone Script İmage